# Plot normalized uniform mixture

Tags: matlab, distribution, probability-density, uniform-distribution, mixture

I need to reproduce the normalized density p(x) below, but the code given does not generate a normalized PDF.

[image: A plot of p of x]

```
clc, clear
% Create three distribution objects with different parameters
pd1 = makedist('Uniform','lower',2,'upper',6);
pd2 = makedist('Uniform','lower',2,'upper',4);
pd3 = makedist('Uniform','lower',5,'upper',6);
% Compute the pdfs
x = -1:.01:9;
pdf1 = pdf(pd1,x); 
pdf2 = pdf(pd2,x); 
pdf3 = pdf(pd3,x); 
% Sum of uniforms
pdf = (pdf1 + pdf2 + pdf3);
% Plot the pdfs
figure;
stairs(x,pdf,'r','LineWidth',2);
```

If I calculate the normalized mixture PDF by simply scaling them by their total sum, I have different normalized probability comparing with the original figure above.

```
pdf = pdf/sum(pdf);
```

Comment: Are these uniform distributions being added?  Or are they being mixed?  If mixed, what are the mixture probabilities?

Comment: For random variables being added, one does not add their PDFs, instead you convolve them.  Based on your clarifications, we can definitely assist you with obtaining the resulting PDF analytically or empirically, and graphing it accordingly.  Just want to make sure we understand the problem correctly.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan Thank you for comment. What I need is a pdf same as the pdf p(x) in the original figure. The code I provided is a simple workaround, but may not be correct. I do not really know whether adding or mixing results in the correct figure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## **Mixture**

A [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) of two random variables means with probability *p* use Distribution 1, and with probability 1-*p* use Distribution 2.

Based on your graph, it appears you are **mixing** the distributions rather than adding (convolving) them.  The precise results matter very much upon the **mixing probabilities**.  As an example, I've chosen `a = 0.25`, `b = 0.35`, and `c = 1-a-b`.

For a mixture, the [probability density function (PDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) is analytically available:
`pdfMix =@(x) a.*pdf(pd1,x) + b.*pdf(pd2,x) + c.*pdf(pd3,x)`.

```
% MATLAB R2018b
pd1 = makedist('Uniform',2,6);
pd2 = makedist('Uniform',2,4);
pd3 = makedist('Uniform',5,6);
a = 0.25;
b = 0.35;
c = 1 - a - b;    % a + b + c = 1

pdfMix =@(x) a.*pdf(pd1,x) + b.*pdf(pd2,x) + c.*pdf(pd3,x);

Xrng = 0:.01:8;
plot(Xrng,pdfMix(Xrng))
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Probability Density Function')
```

[image: Mixture probability density function.]

Since the distributions being mixed are uniform you could also use the [`stairs()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html) command:  `stairs(Xrng,pdfMix(Xrng))`.

We can verify this is a valid PDF by ensuring the total area is 1.
`integral(pdfMix,0,9)`

> ans = 1.0000

---

## **Convolution: Adding Random Variables**

Adding the random variables together yields a different result. Again, this can be done empirically easily.  It is possible to this analytically. For example, convolving two Uniform(0,1) distributions yields a Triangular(0,1,2) distribution. The [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) of random variables is just a fancy way of saying we **add them up** and there is a way to obtain the resulting PDF using integration if you're interested in analytical results.

```
N = 80000;                  % Number of samples
X1 = random(pd1,N,1);       % Generate samples     
X2 = random(pd2,N,1);
X3 = random(pd3,N,1);

X = X1 + X2 + X3;           % Convolution
```

Notice the change of scale for the x-axis (`Xrng = 0:.01:16;`).

[image: Resulting histogram from convolution (adding RVs)]

To obtain this, I generated 80k samples from each distribution with  [`random()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.random.html) then added them up to obtain 80k samples of the desired convolution. Notice when I used [`histogram()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) I used the `'Normalization', 'pdf'` option.

```
Xrng = 0:.01:16;
figure, hold on, box on
p(1) = plot(Xrng,pdf(pd1,Xrng),'DisplayName','X1 \sim U(2,6)')
p(2) = plot(Xrng,pdf(pd2,Xrng),'DisplayName','X2 \sim U(2,4)')
p(3) = plot(Xrng,pdf(pd3,Xrng),'DisplayName','X3 \sim U(5,6)')
h = histogram(X,'Normalization','pdf','DisplayName','X = X1 + X2 + X3')

% Cosmetics
legend('show','Location','northeast')
for k = 1:3
    p(k).LineWidth = 2.0;
end
title('X = X1 + X2 + X3 (50k samples)')
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Probability Density Function (PDF)')
```

You can obtain an estimate of the PDF using the [`fitdist()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitdist.html) and the [Kernel distribution object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.kerneldistribution.html) then calling the [`pdf()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.pdf.html) command on the resulting Kernel distribution object.

```
pd_kernel = fitdist(X,'Kernel')

figure, hold on, box on
h = histogram(X,'Normalization','pdf','DisplayName','X = X1 + X2 + X3')
pk = plot(Xrng,pdf(pd_kernel,Xrng),'b-')           % Notice use of pdf command
legend('Empirical','Kernel Distribution','Location','northwest')
```

If you do this, you'll notice the resulting kernel is unbounded but you can correct this since you know the bounds using [`truncate()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/sldo/ref/prob.normaldistribution.truncate.html).  You could also use the [`ksdensity()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html) function, though the probability distribution object approach is probably more user friendly due to [all the functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/working-with-probability-distributions.html) you have direct access to. You should be aware that the kernel is an approximation (you can see that clearly in the kernel plot). In this case, the integration to convolve 3 uniform distributions isn't too bad, so finding the PDF analytically is probably the preferred choice if the PDF is desired. Otherwise, empirical approaches (especially for generation), are probably sufficient though this depends on your application.

```
pdt_kernel = truncate(pd_kernel,9,16)
```

### [image: Kernel density]

Generating samples from mixtures and convolutions is a different issue (but manageable).

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for answer.  I have a question. Is it possible to reproduce the same figure by convolving pdfs?

Comment: It is possible to produce the resulting distribution both analytically and empirically.  To be clear, you're interested the distribution of `X = X1 + X2 + X3`?  I have that ready to go and can post when you confirm.  Note, it looks nothing like the mixture PDF.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could explain how to the generate and plot the convolved pdf. Thank you.

Comment: @sci9 I added some links and high-level explanations. Can adjust if there's still questions. Just let me know.

Comment: @sci9 Realized I didn't include how to get the estimated density function.  I've added two methods to use a kernel.  The other object is direct integration as the wiki page shows.