# How to obtain an equation for a line fitted to data

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, probability-density, probability-distribution

I am trying to obtain an equation for a function fitted to some histogram data, I was thinking of trying to do this by fitting a rational function as the data doesn't resemble any distribution recognisable by myself.

The data is experimental, and I want to be able to generate a random number according to its distribution. Hence I am hoping to be able to fit it to some sort of PDF from which I can obtain a CDF, which can be rearranged to a function into which a uniformly distributed random number between 0 and 1 can be substituted in order to obtain the desired result.

I have attempted to use the `histfit` function, which has worked but I couldn't figure out how to obtain an equation for the curve it fitted. Is there something stupid I have missed?

**Update**: I have discovered the function `rationalfit`, however I am struggling to figure out what the inputs need to be.

**Further Update**: Upon exploring the `histfit` command further I have discovered the option to fit it to a `kernal`, the figure for which looks promising, however I am only able to obtain a set of *x* and *y* values for the curve, not its equation as a I wanted.

Comment: Noticed that `histfit` supose that your data follow a normal distribution. So you still need to know where your data come from and what is the best distribution for those data.

Comment: You can specify a distribution other than normal, e.g. `histfit(b,10,'beta')` for a beta distribution.

Comment: Depending on your data, it may be appropriate to estimate the empirical distribution using the methods in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56759220/8239061) if you don't want to assume a theoretical distribution. Of course, this depends on the data and the application context.

Comment: What are you going to do with the equation?  Why are you fitting?  I can provide some approaches but my response depends on these things.

Comment: I have a set of experimental data, which can vary greatly depending on certain parameters of the experiment. I am looking for a method to generically find a PDF so I can find a CDF that I can rearrange to get a function that can be used to generate a function according to that distribution.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation on `histfit`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/histfit.html):

> **Algorithms**
>
> `histfit` uses `fitdist` to fit a distribution to data. Use `fitdist`
>   to obtain parameters used in fitting.

So the answer to your question is to use `fitdist` to get the parameters you're after. Here's the example from the documentation:

```
rng default; % For reproducibility
r = normrnd(10,1,100,1);
histfit(r)
```

[image]

```
pd = fitdist(r,'Normal')

pd = 
  NormalDistribution

  Normal distribution
       mu = 10.1231   [9.89244, 10.3537]
    sigma =  1.1624   [1.02059, 1.35033]
```

Comment: Hello, my data is slightly horrible looking and doesn't resemble any distribution that I can recognise, which is why I was hopping that I could try to fit it to a rational function. Is there a way to do this?